# twitter feed on website that is in a repeating box confusion

Tags: twitter, web, repeat

I have a twitter feed on my website and i'm trying to put it in a box that has a top, a middle section that repeats as needed to accommodate text and a bottom image as well as an image below the bottom. the problem is that originally the feed was in a box that didn't repeat or anything the feed was just on top of the box, but now i can't get the box set up right or the feed to do it's thing. here is my code:

```
#twitter_update_list {
overflow: hidden;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 20px;
padding-top: 0;
padding-right: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}

#twitter_update_list li {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#000000;
list-style: none;
}

#twitter_update_list li a {
color:#f7f6e7;
text-decoration: none;
}

#twitter_update_list li a:hover {
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: dotted;
border-bottom-color: #f7f6e7;
}

.twitter_top {
position:absolute;
left:632px;
top: 39px;
    width: 333px;
    height: 27px;
    background:url(twittertop.png);
}

.twitter_mid {
width: 333px;
background:url(twittermiddle.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
padding: 0 15px;
}

.twitter_bot {
width: 333px;
height: 27px;
background:url(twitterbottom.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

    .twitter_whale {
    width: 140px;
    height: 67px;
    left: 900px;
    background-image: url(Layer-6.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 9px;
    line-height: 13px;
    }





<div class="twitter_top"></div>
<div class="twitter_mid">
<ul id="twitter_update_list"></ul>
</div>
<div class="twitter_bot"></div>
<div class="twitter_whale">


    <div id="twitter_div"><ul id="twitter_update_list"><li></li></ul></div>

(update list i'm not putting in here because it's just the js)
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="twitter_box">
  <div id="twitter_top">
  </div>

  <div id="twitter_middle">
  </div>

  <div id="twitter_bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would think it would make more sense to contain them all in one div, from here you can set your styles, since you want the middle part to expand leave the height dynamic.